# Mobile Web App: <header> vs <div data-role="header">. What is the difference?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, mobile-application

I'm doing mobile web application with HTML5 and jQuery mobile. 
[HTML5 Mobile Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile) suggests this:

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>

    </header>
    <div id="main" role="main">

    </div>

    <footer>

    </footer>
  </div> <!--! end of #container -->
</body>
```

On [jQuery mobile (Section "Putting it together: Basic single page template")](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html) it is suggested

```
<body> 
    <div data-role="page">

        <div data-role="header"></div>

        <div data-role="content"></div>

        <div data-role="footer"></div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Which way is more preferable? 
What is the difference between `<header>` and `data-role="header"`?

I did try googling for that, but no answer so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) are for providing information for scripts on your website.  They have no wider semantic purpose outside of providing that data to your scripts, it only means something in your page on your site.

The `<header>` element is an HTML5 element which is defined to mean 'a group of introductory or navigational aids' in [the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element).  It means the same thing in all HTML documents everywhere.

You should use `header`, providing your target audience has HTML5 capable browsers and what you are marking up is a header.  You could additionally use `data-*` attributes like this:

```
<header data-role="header"></header>
```

It shouldn't really make any difference to jQuery mobile what elements are used.

Comment: Believe it or not, `<header>` only applies to sectional elements. The header of a page isn't supposed to be marked as `<header>` (per the spec).

Comment: @VinnyBurgh Can you point out where in the spec it says that?  One of the examples in the spec (which I linked to) uses `header` as a child of `body`.

Comment: @VinnyBurgh http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#sections - first element that is a section: the `body` element.

Comment: @VinnyBurgh If you really want to be convinced, go to the [WHATWG edition of the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-header-element), do a view source and have a look at what the first element in the `body` is.

Answer (score 2):

A [`data-*`](http://developers.whatwg.org/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) attribute contains no semantic value; it only allows scripts to access data from the markup. Therefore, the `data-role` attribute (not to be confused with the [`role`](http://www.w3.org/TR/role-attribute/) attribute) is only relevant for jQuery Mobile.

The [`header`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/header) element has semantic meaning, but if you are to use it in a jQuery Mobile application, you will need to also use `data-role="header"`.

Comment: Thanks. After reading a few articles I got hang of data-* attributes.